# Getting source from object file

Tags: c

Is there any way to get the source code by using object file in C?

For example I have a source code simple.c

> cc simple.c

Now I have a.out (object file). By this a.out whether can I get the source?

> code of simple.c

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/ :-)

Comment: I think `a.out` is not the object file, it is the executable file. So you need `-c`  flag to generate the object file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are many useful tools to retrieve information from your executable. None of them is able to give you back the original source code (as some other user pointed out, it's impossible for C), but you can try some reverse engineering tools. My preferred one are:

- Objdump (part of the "binutils" package)
- hte (debian packages it as "ht")

With the first one you can actually get all the exported symbols and their relative executable code in terms of assembly (obviously this is true only for the `.text` sections). The second one is aimed to work with intel architectures, but you will be able to analize every executable file and get information about the ELF sections and symbols.

Answer (score 66):

No. Turning a cow into hamburger is fairly easy. Turning hamburger into a living cow, somewhat more difficult.

Comment: Perhaps because I had the intuition before looking up, this answer is actually helpful!

Comment: first off, funny response, secondly, inaccurate analogy. thirdly, getting a cow from a hamburger is possible. With skills and tools, a scientist could take a somatic cell, transfer the DNA to an egg, implant the egg into a mother-cow, and there you go.

Comment: @1c1cle: So in your mind that doesn't qualify as "somewhat more difficult" than butchering a cow?

Comment: "somewhat more difficult"

Comment: @1c1cle Turning a hamburger into a (living) cow is probably as difficult as turning x86 assembler code back into a well written (and even documented) c++ source code.

Comment: The statement could be interpreted in more than one way, but I believe it would be helpful to tighten the restrictions to match the reversal process: *"**A** living cow"* should probably be something like *"**the exact same** living cow"*. Maybe also prudent to leave a disclaimer, that no animals were harmed in conducting this thought experiment. @1c1cle: This answer says *"more difficult"*, not *"impossible"*. Also, your proposed procedure is insufficient. It produces a cow that can be used to make the same hamburger. It doesn't restore, say, memories, the moral equivalent of code comments.

Answer (score 1):

The words for the programs you are looking for are "[disassembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler)" (turning the machine language in a.out into assembly language) and "[decompiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decompiler)" (turning assembly language into C, as explained by Dacav, it is much more difficult and the result is never satisfying).

But using a Web search engine with these words may yield results.

Answer (score 0):

No.

With reverse engineering (reading the disassembly) one could reconstruct the logic, but the variable names, comments, etc. will usually be lost.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Linux, use gdb

$`gdb a.out`

(gdb) `list`

Comment: That's can not work unless compiling with `-g` flag.

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the strings present in the executable with the command strings if you are using linux.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34563816)