# How do I change embed design of an exe application in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, embed

Is it possible to change an exe application design, example the calculator in windows xp or windows 7, can i some how embed the calculator into visual studio vb.net and change its design only like put different graphics around it, it will still work same way just design change. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need the code to do that. Extracting the code from a executable application is complicated most of the times: [Why can't we extract source code from executable file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24283493/why-cant-we-extract-source-code-from-executable-file)